# What kind of Library that will handle URL Linked Documents

Tags: sharepoint-library

What kind of library do I need to set-up in order to be able to put a URL like on the *Document* which will allow that *Document* to be access by a Web Playable Program?

I will post the *Document* to the Library and then assign a URL to that *Document*.

Then the URL will be copied into a Training System to allow users to tab the URL and the Document to be pulled up.

Answer (score 0):

which version of SharePoint are you using? If it's SP 2016 or SP Online you can create a guest link once you upload the document that will allow the document to be accessed by other people/systems that don't have access to the list.

Comment: We have 2010 but will be switching over to 2013

Comment: Ah, then as Norman suggested, you are probably best created a custom list or document library. Then in the list/library creating a custom column of type 'Link/Url'. Then when you upload the document you can fill in the Link/Url field or if you don't know it at that time you can update the document item later with the Link/Url

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a custom List and add a 'Link/URL' type column.

Comment: So I would put my Document in a List then add a URL Column on the List which would connect the Document so others in a different system would be able to pull up the document from the list by clicking on the URL that was assigned to that Document in the LIst?

Comment: You upload your document to a document library, you will create a list and add a column to hold the URL of your document uploaded in document library.